# USB 2.0 Options for board with USB 1.1

Tags: usb, motherboard, pci, expansion-cards

I have a QDI Superb 4 board which by default supports USB 1.1. However, I want it to support USB 2.0. How can I go about doing this?

I know there are PCI expansion cards with USB 2.0 and there are also 3.5" floppy replacement panels with USB 2.0. Will these be supported by the board or will it be downgraded to USB 1.1?

If so, are there better options than those already mentioned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 3.5" floppy panels may only function at 1.1 speeds depending on how they connect to your computer.

The PCI card's the best bet as it's going to be its own chipset + controller.

Comment: I'm probably just going to go with the PCI, since the 3.5" floppy panels connect through USB, probably meaning that unless I use the PCI's USBs, the panel will become backwards compatible to USB 1.1 anyways. Thanks!

Comment: @Wesley: correct, the panels generally plug into another USB chipset and are limited to whatever that chipset supports.  ("become backwards compatible" isn't correct, but that's semantics.)  to fix your problem you need a USB2 chipset, which is provided by the PCI card.

Answer (score 1):

If you put an extension PCI USB 2.0 adapter, it will work. Your matherboard just happens to have 1.1 chipset. It will not interfere with an extra adapter.